# Working with arrays of objects as props in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, reactjs

I'm building a small app that consumes a REST api. I'm running into problems displaying information inside arrays of objects, see code below:

**actions.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios'

function fetchService () {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/ldbws-rest-proxy/v0.1/departure-board/IPS')
    .then(function (response) {
      return {
        service: response.data.trainServices[0]
      }
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
}

export default fetchService
```

**train_service.js**

```js
import fetchService from '../actions'

import DepartureTime from './departure_time'
import OriginStation from './origin_station'

var TrainService = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      service: []
    }
  },
  componentDidMount () {
    fetchService()
      .then(function (dataObj) {
        this.setState({
          service: dataObj.service
        })
      }.bind(this))
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <section>
        <DepartureTime time={this.state.service.std} />
        <OriginStation name={this.state.service.origin[0].crs} />
      </section>
    )
  }
})

export default TrainService
```

**JSON sample (response.data.trainServices[0])**

```json
{
  "destination": [
    {
      "crs": "CBG",
      "locationName": "Cambridge"
    }
  ],
  "etd": "On time",
  "operator": "Greater Anglia",
  "operatorCode": "LE",
  "origin": [
    {
      "crs": "IPS",
      "locationName": "Ipswich"
    }
  ],
  "serviceID": "ILZn7gyLj+eoZZfyaFlP0w==",
  "std": "12:20"
}
```

---

The problem is that `<OriginStation name={this.state.service.origin[0].crs} />` throws an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.service.origin')
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working, if I do `console.log(dataObj.service.origin[0].crs)` inside componentDidMount it outputs fine. I think it's something to do with the origin array...

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

Screenshot of the state in the Chrome Inspector:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you check your actual `TrainService` state with something like `React Developer Tools` in Chrome browser?

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `TrainService` render method calls earlier than `fetchService` promise resolves. 
Easiest way to fix your error is wait for `fetchService` updates `service` state:

```
var TrainService = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      service: null
    }
  },
  componentDidMount () {
    fetchService()
      .then(function (dataObj) {
        this.setState({
          service: dataObj.service
        })
      }.bind(this))
  },
  render () {
    if (this.state.service === null)
      return null;
    return (
      <section>
        <DepartureTime time={this.state.service.std} />
        <OriginStation name={this.state.service.origin[0].crs} />
      </section>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank-you, I hadn't considered that. Is there a way that React can handle this for me e.g. by using componentWillMount or something similar that can wait for things like this?

Comment: @lkemitchll I don't think so, because you (but not React core) calls async method. It's ok, because async request not freeze whole application. You can set some data in initial state (componentDidMount) to show user some data before it really loads

Answer (score 0):

`fetchService` is making an async call. So when `componentDidMount` is run, it will make an async call and proceeds to `render`.

When the `render` function is executed for the first time you state is not populated with the data and it has an empty array for `this.state.service`, from `getInitialState`.

If you are writing console.log inside componentDidMount as

```
componentDidMount () {
    fetchService()
        .then(function (dataObj) {
             console.log(dataObj.service.origin[0].crs)
             this.setState({
                  service: dataObj.service
             })
        }.bind(this))
},
```

the console.log gets executed only when the async call has succeeded, so the data is available.

To solve this either don't render the component until the state data is ready.

```
render() {
    this.state.service.length == 0 && return null
    ...
}
```